# check if form is submitted successfully html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, forms

I have following code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="store_account_name">Store Title</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="store_account_name" id="store_account_name" placeholder="Please insert store title of the external store" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="store_url">Store URL</label>
    <input type="url" value="" class="form-control" name="store_url" id="store_url" placeholder="Please insert store URL as described in help section" required />
</div>
```

On submit button I want to check if form is validated. I have an listner event which has preventDefault button. So I want to send ajax call only when both of these inputs are successfully validated. Is there any JS function to check the status of validation or any css property is add to invalid field.

Comment: Right now when form is submitted ajax call is made even if fields are not validated. Ajax call should only be made when fields are successfully validated.

Comment: Please, change the title. You need something like this: 'Add event listener on form submitting'. You definitely do not need to check if a form was submitted.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use the form's `onsubmit` event. It sounds like you are listening on the submit button's click event which isn't right.

The form's submit event will only fire if the form is valid. The HTML5 validation rules will prevent this event from firing if the form is invalid.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2X2NE/)

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // do ajax now
    console.log("submitted"); 
});
```

Comment: It will do the ajax even if the fields are not validated.

Comment: Not true at all. It will not fire if the form is invalid. See fiddle in answer.

Comment: Thanks your answer was correct. The problem is I have included a js file that create problem. That js file require the form to have data-validate="true" attribute and when it is placed it overrides its functionality.

Comment: It does not answer the question 'check if form is submitted successfully html5'. Your examples only shows how to make an ajax call and prevent default form submitting. Maybe the answer resolves the problem of those who asked, but nothing more. The question is open. Remove `required` attributes from jsfiddle example, and your code would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, I think this is what you are looking for-

on '`onsubmit`' attribute of '`form`' call a function. In that function, do the validation, and then make an ajax call if the fields are valid, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 1):

try this function:

```
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
    var form = $(this).parents("form:first");
    form.submit(function () {
        //  validate submitted successfully according to html validation
        //  ajax here
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

If you would use php and json for your plan it would be clear and answering fine like other great projects.
if form submittet redponse to clients the results if not throw an error via json.